# Update SDk Android Studio, Path profile!

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sdk

Formatei meu pc e instalei o android Studio e tenho em uma unidade especifica a pasta do androidSdk separada. Ao atualizar o Sdk, ocorre o seguinte erro:

> An error occurred while preparing SDK package Android Wear ARM EABI
>   v7a System Image:
>   C:\Users\NoteS\AppData\Local\Temp\PackageOperation03\armeabi-v7a-25_r03.zip
>   (O sistema não pode encontrar o caminho especificado).

Como faço pra trocar esse caminho, *C:\Users\NoteS,* pois esse "*NoteS*" era o nome do usuário antigo(formatado).

Comment: Felipe, poderia me informar se você mudou o caminho do SDK referenciado no Android Studio?

Comment: Sim. Tipo, quando faço 'open an existing android studio project', ele aparece seguinte mensagem: 

'The path
'D:\android-sdk'
does not belong to a directory.

Android Studio will use this Android SDK instead:
'F:\android-sdk'
and will modify the project's local.properties file.

Mas aí segue normalmente. Só quando tento update no Sdk.

Answer (score 0):

Em Settings -> Android SDK você consegue alterar o path de instalação do SDK.

Comment: Já está configurado no novo caminho. O negócio é o update do Sdk. Muda esse ''Local\Temp''
vlw.

Comment: Tenta isso: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30613890/7898322